# Magento 2: Sort Product Collection by date added to category

Tags: magento2, product-collection

From a category page, I grab the product collection from the category object like so

```
$productCollection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

However, the results are sorted in the reverse order of how they appear on the category page. The products on the category page are sorted in the same way they are in the Magento admin (which I assume is simply 'date added to category').

Is there a way I can use

```
$productCollection->setOrder()
```

In a way that returns my collection in the same order as they appear on the category page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter product collection by updated date or create date DESC/ASC order.

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToSort('update_at', 'ASC');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. In my case addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC') did it, which I assume is the way they are sorted by default somewhere in Magento

Answer (score 3):

You can try `$productCollection->setOrder('position','ASC');` to load collection by position in ASC order.

You can use different parameters in the `setOrder()` for example `entity_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` etc and `ASC` and `DSC` for their appearing order.

Comment: Thanks, along with the answer from sangeeta this also worked, specifically: setOrder('created_at','DESC') matched the order of the products on the category.