# Sort product collection by date in standart category view

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, collection, sorting, porto-theme

I'm running Magento CE 2.3.3 with Porto theme.
I want to sort the products in the category overview by the date they were added without using an extra extension.
By default products in category view/category pages can be sortet by either *position*, *product name*, *size*, *price*. The pre selected sorting attribut is *position*.

Although there is a way to define new attributes, there is no way to create an attribute that sorts by date resp. *newest first*.

What is the smartest way to add this feature to Magento without adding much new code?
The question is related to the questions in these threads:[Magento 2: Sort Product Collection by date added to category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290974/magento-2-sort-product-collection-by-date-added-to-category) and [Sort products by Date](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146727/sort-products-by-date)... Unfortunately I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All products have a *created_at* attribute containing the date the product was added. You can enable this as a frontend sort option in two ways.

If you have access to your database:

- Find the created_at product attribute in DB table eav_attribute

  - set
    its column frontend_label to Created At(default is null).
- Find the created_at product attribute in DB table
  catalog_eav_attribute

  - set its column used_for_sort_by to 1(default
    is 0).
- Refresh caches

Created At will now be available as a frontend sort option which you can set as the default sort option in admin. The more conventional way to do this is via a module where you change the database fields using the setup methods.

You can find more information about both ways here:

[Magento 2 How to add custom sort by option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option/195138#195138)

I find using the created_at attribute to sort products very useful because if you want to push products to the top of the list you can always manually set the created_at attribute with something like

```
$product->setCreatedAt($now);
```

Needless to say you should test this on your dev shop and make sure you have a (working) backup before you change anything.

Comment: Can you take a lookk at my question
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358299/magento2-4-how-to-sort-products-by-sizes-m-l-xl